Getting price information using the Safe public API
The current public documentation includes an endpoint: /api/v1/safes/{SAFE_ADDRESS}/balances/usd which is meant to provide users with a fiat balance and conversion rate for every asset held in a safe, but the API will always return back "0.0" for the following fields: "fiatBalance", "fiatConversion", "ethValue".
Is there any way to return the appropriate values from the API? The only known query params for the endpoint are trusted and exclude_spam, neither of which resolve the issue mentioned.

The /balances and /balances/usd are both deprecated. Please refer to our API reference for an up-to-date list of working endpoints.
Best, Louis
